# Facebook multi-friends selector height too small

Tags: facebook, multi-friend-selector

I have a Facebook friends selector on my website.  It was working perfectly but now for some reason the height is the same as if its a log in iframe.

[image]

It cuts off the friends and is basically useless.

Here are my settings in facebook

[image]

How can I have the  normal automatically size facebook friend selector I used to have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wrong dialog height is a bug in facebook apprequest, to fix it add this style where you are using it.
Let's hope facebook staff fix it soon.

```
<style>
.fb_dialog_content iframe { height:537px !important; } 
</style>
```

You have more info [here](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/194725433940802)